# two name nodes are stand by after configuring HA

Tags: hadoop

i have configured high availability in my cluster
which consists of three nodes

hadoop-master(192.168.4.128)(name node)

hadoop-slave-1(192.168.4.111) (another name node )

hadoop-slave-2 (192.168.4.106) (data node)

without formatting name node ( converting a non-HA-enabled cluster to be HA-enabled) as described here
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html

but i got two name nodes working as standby 
so i tried to move the transition of one of these two nodes  to active by applying the following command

```
 hdfs haadmin -transitionToActive mycluster --forcemanual
```

with the following out put

```
17/04/03 08:07:35 WARN ha.HAAdmin: Proceeding with manual HA state management even though
automatic failover is enabled for NameNode at hadoop-master/192.168.4.128:8020
17/04/03 08:07:36 WARN ha.HAAdmin: Proceeding with manual HA state management even though
automatic failover is enabled for NameNode at hadoop-slave-1/192.168.4.111:8020
Illegal argument: Unable to determine service address for namenode 'mycluster'
```

my core-site is

```
<property>
                 <name>dfs.tmp.dir</name>
                 <value>/opt/hadoop/data15</value>
       </property>
        <property>
           <name>fs.default.name</name>
           <value>hdfs://hadoop-master:8020</value>
       </property>
       <property>
           <name>dfs.permissions</name>
           <value>false</value>
       </property>
       <property>
           <name>dfs.journalnode.edits.dir</name>
           <value>/usr/local/journal/node/local/data</value>
       </property>

        <property>

                <name>fs.defaultFS</name>

                <value>hdfs://mycluster</value>

        </property>


        <property>

                <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>

                <value>/tmp</value>


  </property>
```

my hdfs-site.xml is

```
<property>
                 <name>dfs.replication</name>
                 <value>2</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                 <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
                 <value>/opt/hadoop/data16</value>
                 <final>true</final>
        </property>
        <property>
                 <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
                 <value>/opt/hadoop/data17</value>
                 <final>true</final>
        </property>

        <property>
                <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
                <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
                <value>hadoop-slave-1:50090</value>
        </property>

       <property>

        <name>dfs.nameservices</name>

        <value>mycluster</value>

        <final>true</final>

    </property>

    <property>

        <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.mycluster</name>

        <value>hadoop-master,hadoop-slave-1</value>

        <final>true</final>

    </property>

    <property>

        <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.mycluster.hadoop-master</name>

        <value>hadoop-master:8020</value>

    </property>

    <property>

        <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.mycluster.hadoop-slave-1</name>

        <value>hadoop-slave-1:8020</value>

    </property>

    <property>

        <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.mycluster.hadoop-master</name>

        <value>hadoop-master:50070</value>

    </property>

    <property>

        <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.mycluster.hadoop-slave-1</name>

        <value>hadoop-slave-1:50070</value>

    </property>

    <property>

        <name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>

        <value>qjournal://hadoop-master:8485;hadoop-slave-2:8485;hadoop-slave-1:8485/mycluster</value>

    </property>

    <property>

        <name>dfs.ha.automatic-failover.enabled</name>

        <value>true</value>

    </property>

    <property>

        <name>ha.zookeeper.quorum</name>



        <value>hadoop-master:2181,hadoop-slave-1:2181,hadoop-slave-2:2181</value>

    </property>

    <property>

        <name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>

        <value>sshfence</value>

    </property>

    <property>

        <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.private-key-files</name>

        <value>root/.ssh/id_rsa</value>

    </property>


    <property>

        <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.connect-timeout</name>

        <value>3000</value>

    </property>
```

what should the service address value be ? and what are  possible solutions i can  apply in order 
to turn on  one name node of the two nodes to active state ?

note the zookeeper server on all three nodes is stopped

Comment: i finally tried to force one of the two name nodes to be active manually by applying

hdfs haadmin -transitionToActive hadoop-master

with the following response

Comment: 17/04/04 03:13:06 WARN ha.HAAdmin: Proceeding with manual HA state management even though
automatic failover is enabled for NameNode at hadoop-slave-1/192.168.4.111:8020
17/04/04 03:13:07 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/04/04 03:13:07 WARN ha.HAAdmin: Proceeding with manual HA state management even though
automatic failover is enabled for NameNode at hadoop-master/192.168.4.128:8020

Comment: Operation failed: End of File Exception between local host is: "hadoop-master/192.168.4.128"; destination host is: "hadoop-master":8020; : java.io.EOFException; For more details see:http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EOFException

Comment: what should i do with two stand by name nodes should i apply name node format on one of these two name nodes

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have same issue

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue, and it turn out that I didn't format zookeeper and start ZKFC